# Approach of sending private messages to specific clients in SocketIO and Android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io, chat, private-messaging

I have a problem with sending private messages using SocketIO on NodeJS as a Server and Android on the client side. The messages do not reach the specific endpoint that I have assigned and I do not understand why that is. 
I know that each time a user connects to SocketIO, he is assigned to a specific socket ID which I save in an object alongside with the socket object using the client name as an identifier. Like so:

```
  // Register your client with the server, providing your username
socket.on('init', function(data) {
  console.log("UserID to be assigned to socket: " + data.userID); // Store a reference to your socket ID
// data.userID is identifier with which I find back the respective client I want to send the message to.
  connectedSockets[data.userID] = { ID: socket.id, usersocket : socket };  // Store a reference to your socket
  console.log("New connected socketID: " + connectedSockets[data.userID].ID + " with socket object: " + connectedSockets[data.userID].usersocket);
});
```

When sending a private message, I want to retrieve this object to send it to the respective person like so:

```
// Send a message to another user

socket.on('privateMessage', function(data){

  // Send message to another user
  console.log("ReceivingID : " + data.recipientID);
  console.log("SocketID used: " + connectedSockets[data.recipientID].ID);

  var userSocket = connectedSockets[data.recipientID].usersocket;
  var socketID = connectedSockets[data.recipientID].ID
  var recipient = data.recipientID;

  io.sockets.userSocket[socketID].emit(recipient, {Message: data.Message});

});
```

However, for some reason I get an undefined error for my socket and ID:

```
var userSocket = connectedSockets[data.recipientID].usersocket;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'usersocket' of undefined
```

I am connecting both clients and both ID's are saved in connectedSockets but I am still getting the undefined error.

Any idea why that is?

Additionally, I was wondering if I am understanding this right. When wanting to send a message to a specific client I am using the socket object received when a client is connecting and the socketID assigned to the client to emit my message with this command:

```
io.sockets.userSocket[socketID].emit(recipient, {Message: data.Message});
```

Is this the right approach on using private messaging in socketIO?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to create a unique room for each user (based on `data.userId`) as soon as they connect? Then you could just send a message to the room, without having to retrieve the actual socket.

Comment: Hi there, the room option is the one I am currently using, this approach works pretty well, however, I prefer to have the flexibility of choosing who I am sending it to directly ;)

Comment: The room approach allows you to send to multiple clients with the same id, for example if they are connected across multiple devices. Whether that would suit your needs is up to you I guess. I'm not sure if you lose any flexibility with this approach